# How to create smooth scrolling on images with different speed?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I am trying to create the scrolling effect like this link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6bOEUONZro9heB4Vo9ZQl9cz8XjLS6F/view?usp=drivesdk

Images scroll with different speed and fade out when it reaches the top of screen

I've done the smooth scrolling part by using smooth scrolling tutorial on Codrops.
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/07/23/smooth-scrolling-image-effects/

But no idea how to create the effect that when scrolling, images move with different speed. Or is there any plugin I can use?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to be logged into pinterest to see what you're talking about? Which platform and browser are you testing this on? FYI: I don't see any of the effects you're talking about on a desktop in Firefox. The demo on tympanus works for me.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post. Putting up a short video for that effects

Answer (score 0):

A library I've used before is [Rellax](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax) - a parallax js library. This one also gives you the possibility to adjust speed for every element.

A demo can be found [right here.](https://dixonandmoe.com/rellax/)